# How to encode URLs in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

How to encode both content and URL of any HTTP request in AngularJs?

I came through these solutions, but they are not enough for me:

for encoding only one request url : `$http.get(encodeURI('your web request url'))`

for content of request:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function(data, headers) {
    return angular.isobject(data) && string(data) !== '[object file]' ? jquery.param(data) : data;
}];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16706920/1898397 looks relevant here.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14512986/1898397 also this one

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom $http interceptor. 
Here you can transform/edit/customize every request, response as well as handling requestErrors and responseErrors

more information: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Answer (score 0):

herre is The Solution I've used :

```
var module = angular.module('youApp');
module.factory('urlUpdater', function() {
    var urlUpdaterConfig = {
        request: function(requestObj) {
            // do whateveerrrrrrrr you want with request object
            return requestObj;
        }
    };
    return urlUpdaterConfig;
});
module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('urlUpdater');
}]);
```